# Location services permission keeps disappearing

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, location

I am working on an app which will display points of interest on a map around the users location. The problem is, when the app loads, the permission dialog disappears instantly before the user can allow or deny permissions.

My code looks like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    logo.animation = "zoomIn"
    logo.duration = 1
    logo.delay = 0.5
    logo.animate()

    formatView()

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let authStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

    if authStatus == .notDetermined {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    if authStatus == .denied || authStatus == .restricted {
        showLocationServicesDeniedAlert()
        return
    }
}
```

But I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Ive tried to follow other answers on here for similar problems but it seems like there are a few reasons this can happen and I have no idea which one my problem is I'm tearing hairs out!

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning `locationManager` to a local variable of `viewDidLoad` which gets released immediately when `viewDidLoad` finishes.  Instead, make `locationManager` a property of your `ViewController`:

```
var locationManager: CLLocationManager?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the the code in `viewWillAppear` as `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` needs to be called when view controller has appeared. And you could study the View Controller Life Cycle [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller) to know more about their appearance, loading and everything.

Comment: That shouldn't be the issue, for me requesting authorization works just fine when calling it from `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor you're right, even it works good for me too but the permission alerts are seems to have problems when called from `viewDidLoad` (sometimes), so that could be the issue he is facing.